# How do I prevent iTunes from syncing 400 apps to my new iPad?

Tags: itunes, ipad, applications

I just got my new iPad and installed the apps I wanted without first syncing it with my computer. When I connect it to my computer and choose to sync apps, iTunes wants to add all my 400+ purchased iPad apps to the iPad, and I don't want that.

Is there an easy way to deselect these 400 apps that I don't want from within iTunes? They are arranged on the last screens after the apps that I actually want.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. So, you've installed 400+ apps on your iPad and you want to prevent the apps from syncing with you computer? Or do you want to prevent the sync of 400+ apps from your computer to your iPad?

Comment: @Michiel The apps have not been synced yet, and I'd prefer to keep it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately iTunes doesn't support selecting multiple applications, apart from manually selecting each one. The best option would be to disable syncing of Applications on iTunes.

For iTunes sync to work correctly you either need to use it to manage your applications, or only use the iPad and download all the applications you want directly to the iPad using the App Store on the iPad.

Comment: If I disable syncing, is the applications' data still backed up?

Comment: @Lizzan Yes. The backup is independently done, whether you backup to iTunes or to iCloud.

Comment: Ah, good, then not syncing might actually be the best option. I'll accept your answer in a day or so if nothing better shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and dug for an answer. What you need to do is instead of using iTunes go into your documents and search 'app' all the files for the apps listed in your iTunes will come up, simply select them all and click delete. This is an easy was to remove a large amount of apps at once. If you want some back simply go into the app store and re download them.

Comment: What do you mean "go into your documents"? How does the user do this? Using what program?

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to do it. On the screen that lists your apps from iTunes, doubleclick on the iPhone-preview and click on the X for each app icon.

Comment: That's still 400 clicks for 400 apps, which is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: But if you keep your mouse above the upper left icon, you just hammer away on the left mousebutton. Each screenful of apps only takes 5 seconds to clear this way.